Maybe a wrong in Riemann curvature tensor of Wiki
Picture below is from Riemann curvature tensor of Wiki, I feel the two red box are contradictory. For example, by there two box, there are
$$
\nabla_a\nabla_b T_i- \nabla_b\nabla_a T_i
=
-R_{~~iab}^j T_j =-g^{jl}R_{iabl} T_j  
\\
 \nabla_b\nabla_a T_i  -  \nabla_a\nabla_b T_i   
=
-R_{~~iba}^j T_j =-g^{jl}R_{ibal} T_j  
$$
But
$$
-g^{jl}R_{iabl} T_j  \ne  g^{jl}R_{ibal} T_j
$$
So, I feel the two red box are contradictory. But since the symbols of Riemann geometry are always confused, I'm not sure. So ask here.
In fact, if the second red box is
$$
R_{ijkl}=g_{ip}R^p_{~~jkl}
$$
then, they are concordant.




Your suggested change seems correct; it also makes sense with the usual Ricci identities.
Also, make sure you are careful using roman/greek letters because it has major implications for which sets you are indexing over.

Thanks，although I made another mistake，this mistake misled me some time.
